# Beginning with the formula for $\sin (a-b)$, derive the formula for $\csc (a-b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Starting with the formula for $\sin(a-b)$, develop a formula for $\csc(a-b)$ in terms of secant and cosecant terms only.

Comment: Hi ToastyyyAnorak, it is very nice for any future question you ask to be formatted using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It makes them a lot easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$sin(a-b) = sin(a)cos(b) - cos(a)sin(b)$. Now we take the reciprocal of the above: 
$$\frac{1}{sin(a)cos(b) - cos(a)sin(b)}$$. multiply the numerator by the conjugate of the denominator, and take it from there. Hope that helps!